# How to obtain a refrence to an OSGi Datasource with parameterised JNDI name?

Tags: apache-camel, talend, apache-karaf

Please forgive my ignorance, but I can't find any resources describing to how to obtain a reference to an OSGi declared datasource without hardcoding the name in the Spring XML definition.

I'm using Talend ESB SE Runtime (6.5.1), and trying to create a route that will be reused with different osgi data sources as the referenced datasource for the route.

If, in the Spring configuration I declare

```
<osgi:reference id="dataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource" filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=myDataSourceName)" />
```

this works. However, I can't see any way of parameterising this, since when I try using

```
<osgi:reference id="dataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource" filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=${app.datasource.name})" />
```

the karaf log complains that it can't find a service called `${app.datasource.name}` which it clearly isn't going to find.

If parameters can't be used in the filter for osgi references, then I could configure this in Java, but I can't see anywhere how I get from a Camel Context registry to the underlying OSGi registry - which the osgi:reference element does in the Spring XML.

If anyone can point me in the right direction here, that would be great, since I suspect I may be misunderstanding how the various components function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's problem of configuring property placeholder, cause there must be value of your app.datasource.name property in log, not property name. Try to use spring xml config like [this](https://gist.github.com/c0ldd/9d810da7677c3b0411ca8fa129532a1b).

Comment: Bingo! I already had the properties configured, but without the property placeholder.